# Concerns with gRPC architecture (gRPC, nginx, docker)

Tags: docker, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-go, grpc-node

I'm currently trying to create a tracing tool for fun (which supports gRPC tracing) and was confused as to whether or not I was thinking about this architecture properly. A tracing tool keeps track of the entire workflow/journey of the request (from the moment a user clicks the button, to when the request goes to the API gateway, between microservices, and back.

Let's say the application is a bookstore, and it is broken up to 2 microservices, maybe account and books. Let's say that there is a User Interface, and when you click a button, it allows a user to favorite a book. I'm only using 2 microservices to keep this example simple.

```
**Different parts of the Fake/Mock up application**
UI -> 
nginx -> I wanted to use this as an API Gateway.
microservice 1 -> (Contains data for all Users of a bookstore) 
microservice 2 -> (Contains data for all the books)
```

**So my goal is to figure a way to trace that request. So we can imagine the request goes to nginx

[image]

**Concern #1:** When the request goes to nginx, it is HTTP. Cool, but when the request is sent to the microservice, it is a grpc call (or over http2). Can nginx get an http request and then send that request over http2...? Not sure if I'm wording this correctly or not. I know nginx plus supports http2. I also know that grpc has a grpc gateway too.

**Concern #2:** Containerization. Do I have to containerize both microservices individually, or would I have to containerize the entire docker container itself. Is it simple to link nginx and docker?

**Concern #3:** When tracing gRPC requests (finding out how much time a request is fulfilled), I'm considering using a middleware logger or a tracing API (opentracing, jaegar, etc.) to do this. How else would I figure out how long it takes for gRPC to make requests?

I was wondering if it was possible to address these concerns, if my thought process is correct, and if this architecture is feature.

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions in the industry are implemented on top of a container orchestration solution (Kubernetes, Docker Swarm, etc).
It is usually not a good idea to "containerize" and manage reverse proxy yourself.
The reverse proxy should be aware of all the containers status (by hooking to orchestrator) and dynamically update its configuration when a container created, crashed, or relocated (due to a machine gets out of service).
Kubernetes handles GRPC using the mesh networks. Please take a look at [kubernetes service mesh](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/).
If you decided to use Traefik and Docker Swarm check out [traefik h2c support](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/grpc/).
In conclusion, consider more modern alternatives to Nginx when you want to load balance GRPC.